# Existe como "linkar" um conteúdo especifico de um repositório no outro?

Tags: git, github

Eu tenho um programa que precisa de algumas `DDLs`, essas `DDLs` estão disponíveis em outro Git, também no GitHub. Sendo assim, seria possível a minha biblioteca *linkar* tal arquivo ao tal repositório?

Para ser mais especifico, existe uma DDL ([github.com/c-smile/.../64/sciter.dll](http://github.com/c-smile/sciter-sdk/tree/master/bin/64/sciter.dll)) e ela é usada na meu programa. Eu queria incluir ela [aqui, junto com o `main.go`](https://github.com/brokenbydefault/Nanollet), ao invés de ter que fazer manualmente.

Teria como criar um `sciter.dll` apontado para o tal GitHub? Um `sciter.dll` que seria fictício, onde ao usar o `go get -x` ou `git clone` iria ir ao `github.com/c-smile` para obter este conteúdo.

Isso é possível, como faria isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que há uma maneira de fazer o que você está pensando, que é linkar um módulo de outro projeto ao seu.

1. Navegue pelo terminar até o diretório do seu projeto e digite: `git submodule add https://github.com/<user>/nomeModulo nomeModulo`
2. Se a versão do seu git for antiga, digite agora esse comando: `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Pronto, você importou o submódulo ao seu projeto!

Answer (score 0):

A boa prática para esse seu problema é usar um; [gerenciador de pacotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) ou [package management](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_gestor_de_pacotes).
Os gerenciadores de pacotes são mais conhecidos dos usuários gerais em sistemas [GNU/Linux](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux), por possibilitarem a instalação de programas ou aplicativos pelo console. Os mais conhecidos são: APT ([Advanced Packaging Tool](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)), RPM ([RPM Package Manager](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_(software))), entre outros... No Windows temos o [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

Já em desenvolvimento de software, quando trabalhamos com [componentização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_software_baseada_em_componentes), com o objetivo de distribuir pedaços da aplicação; deve existir a preocupação de como distribuir esse componente. Já que duplicar código não é uma alternativa, e não centralizar a distribuição do componente, pode levar ao desuso deste em grandes empresas. Para isso servem os gerenciadores de pacote!

Usados tanto para componentes do back-end como front-end temos opções específicas para cada linguagem ou plataforma. Segue relação de vários conhecidos:

- Java: [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)
- .Net: [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/)
- Go: veja relação [aqui](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools)

Se os seus pacotes puderem ser públicos, deve existir um repositório para Go que você possa usar. Daí o seu processo de build deverá ter acesso a esse repositório para usar o pacote publicado. Se tiver que ser privado, você deverá ter na sua infra-estrutura essa gestão.

Você também pode procurar por gerenciadores de pacotes universai, que aceitam diversos feeds, de diversas linguagens. Dê uma olhada no [Azure DevOps Packages](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/devops/artifacts/).

Comment: Isso me parece aumentar mais a complexidade do que reduzi-la. A dll (so, dylib) é usada somente para a interface gráfica. Quando faz o `clone` (ou usa `go get`) poderá executar o `go generator` que irá passar o dll para uma variável qualquer, já que compilar estaticamente não funciona. Assim, a cada uso essa dll é descompactada pela aplicação e consumida. A razão de importa-lo para o GitHub é para facilitar a compilação, já que não terá que copiar as dlls manualmente, se for compilar. Para o uso geral, o resultado do `go build`, o `exe`, já é suficiente. Ou, entendi seu post errado.

Comment: Eu não entendi pedaços do seu texto, portanto não tive a compreenção total do seu processo.
A dll em questão, é de um projeto público? Externo ao seu/ou sua empresa?
O que você quer dizer com "descompactar a dll", já que não é possível descompactar um binário.
Se o go build é suficiente, em qual momento você usa essa outra compilação e para quê?

Comment: A dll é publica, não é produzida por mim. O `go build` é preciso somente se alguém quiser alterar o meu código, que é aberto. Acredito que é ideal facilitar a edição. A ddl é embutida dentro do meu programa. Quando usa o `go generate` adiconado um código cria o `sciter_windows.go` ele terá o `var DLL = {0x00.binario..}`. Quando você for usar o programa, a `dll` vai ser descompactada (tipo `os.Write(DLL)`) e então usada. Para o usuário final, que baixa já o `exe`, não há qualquer necessidade de ter a dll, porque ele já tem. O problema é quem quer compilar que acaba tendo que baixar manualmente.

Comment: Em resumo, a dll é necessária porque ela faz parte do código, literalmente. Então para alguém compilar (para criar o tal `var DLL = {conteudo do dll}`) terá que ter as dlls. Atualmente a pessoa deve ir no site da Sciter e baixa-la, então inclui-la na pasta e depois usar o `go generate`, isso me parece uma perde da tempo. Se eu incluir as dlls direto no meu GitHub terei que ficar atualizando, mas essa ainda parece ser a melhor saída, mas tem a questão das licenças.

Comment: É uma decisão sua... eu dei a melhor prática, que é o usado pelo mercado, e o por que não é uma perda de tempo.